# How to stop iframe from preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm using a slider (Royal Slider) with multiple html pages as slides instead of images, I'm using these in separate iframes!

some of these html pages contain animations, is there a way of only loading the html content when the page is accessed as at the moment when I get to the relevant page the animation has already finished as I guess they have preloaded!

Comment: Wow, that's one run-on sentence. It also makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can leave the `src` of the `iframe` empty and update it when you want to load it